# How to manage BroadcastReceiver through AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I have an Activity, here are two button :

1. Button One for "Choose Alarm Time ". When I tap on it TimePicker appear and I choose time for the Alarm.
2. Button Two for "Set the Alarm". When I tap on it, alarm Set.

**What I am Doing :**

On the set Alarm time I'll Call the `BroadcastReceiver`. For the demo I print only time of the Alarm what I set and A string in the `Toast`

**What is Query :**

"  If I set the alarm time like, **Current Time 4.00 PM** and I set the **Alarm Time 6.00 PM**. In this case Alarm always call the `BroadcastReceiver` and it's `Work Fine`.

`BUT`

If **Current time is 4.00 PM** and I set the **Alarm 2.00 PM** then It call `BroadCastReceiver` at the same time AND I DO NOT WANT THIS THING."

.

**For the AlarmManager I use this snippet :**

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(SetAlarm.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(SetAlarm.this, BroadCast.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetAlarm.this, 0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Down voter , please make it right if I asked something wrong or suggest me what I did or ask wrong ?

Comment: This looks like a legitimate question to me. +1

Comment: do this, inside the broadcast receiver, check the time, i presume u are storing the value inside a shared preference or something of the sort, compare the current time n the time set for the day. If it before the current time, dont do anything else perform the operation @AM  I faced the same with a service, and so i had to solve it by putting in the condition

Comment: time what I am getting is 2.00 PM according to my query. Means If alarm time before the current time than broadcast call at the same time when I tab on SET ALARM. @DharaShah

Comment: yes so then put the broadcaster call in the if or else condition :)

Comment: okay... but if i do this thing than How can alarm will set for the next time . @DharaShah

Comment: jus like the way it was before.. i mean all u have to do is, check the currnt time with wat the query returns, and if the current time is more than the time received, dont do anything, else broadcast. Are u doing anything in the broadcast receiver ? then check for the same in the recevier,and set the alarm anyway /

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()<System.currentTimeMillis())
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

you can do something like this.